# How can I test React Router with Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, react-router, jestjs

I have not been able to test [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) with `context` successfully. I am using

- react 0.13.3
- react-router 0.13.3
- jest 0.3.0
- node 0.10.33

and have tried these approaches:

- https://labs.chie.do/jest-testing-with-react-router/
- https://gist.github.com/alanrubin/da3f740308eb26b20e70

**Is there a definitive example?**

All links to the ["super-secret guide"](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/testing.md) mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224770/154065) (which does not use Jest) are now broken. When I was able to view that guide, it didn't provide any more information than the first link listed above.

Comment: 'Super secrete guide' can now be found at https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/testing.md

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for exactly, but I got around this by making a helper function that I use when writing jest tests for components that depend on router state.

```
//router-test-helper
var Router = require('react-router'),
    Route = Router.Route,
    TestLocation = require('react-router/lib/locations/TestLocation');

module.exports = function(React){
    TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
    return {
        getRouterComponent: function(targetComponent, mockProps) {
            var component,
                div = document.createElement('div'),
                routes = [
                    React.createFactory(Route)({
                        name: '/',
                        handler: targetComponent
                    })
                ];

            location = new TestLocation('/');
            Router.run(routes, location, function (Handler) {
                var mainComponent = React.render(React.createFactory(Handler)(mockProps), div);
                component = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(mainComponent, targetComponent);
            });
            return component;
        }
    };
};
```

I didn't write all of this on my own, most of it I think I pulled from that now defunct guide you linked to.   If I remember right... it's been a while.

After you have that you can use this in your tests kinda like this.

```
//test-example
jest.dontMock('../src/js/someComponent');
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var routerHelper = require('../router-test-helper')(React);
var SomeComponent = require('../srcs/js/someComponent');

describe('Some Component', function(){
    it('should be testable', function(){
        var mockProps = {}; 
        var renderedComponent = routerHelper.getRouterComponent(SomeComponent, mockProps);
        // Test your component as usual from here.....
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////

        var inputs = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(renderedComponent, 'input');
        //blah blah blah
    });
});
```

*This assumes you have React and the helper in your unmocked module paths*

If you're actually trying to test things specific to certain routes, or transitioning between routes... I'm not sure if this is a good approach. May be better to use something more intergration test-y, like selenium or something.. Also... this probably won't work once the 1.0 of react router comes out. But it may be even easier to test things thing 'The React Way'(tm)  because all the routing stuff will be handled through props.   At least that's the impression I get from the the little bit I've read into it.

Comment: Thank you, @ericf89. I got a bit farther using your suggestion, but ran into some mocking issues. Before I pushed on, I realized that I do not need to use “context” and should go back to mixins. My mistake was browsing the GitHub repository on the v0.13.3 tag. I didn’t see the updated Upgrade Guide and was instead following https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v0.13.3/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md instead. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who happens to stuck with this problem.
Here's the setup that I've ended up with for my context dependent components (stripped down for simplicity, of course):

```
// dontmock.config.js contains jest.dontMock('components/Breadcrumbs')
// to avoid issue with hoisting of import operators, which causes 
// jest.dontMock() to be ignored

import dontmock from 'dontmock.config.js';
import React from "react";
import { Router, createMemoryHistory } from "react-router";
import TestUtils from "react-addons-test-utils";

import Breadcrumbs from "components/Breadcrumbs";

// Create history object to operate with in non-browser environment
const history = createMemoryHistory("/products/product/12");

// Setup routes configuration.
// JSX would also work, but this way it's more convenient to specify custom 
// route properties (excludes, localized labels, etc..).
const routes = [{
  path: "/",
  component: React.createClass({
    render() { return <div>{this.props.children}</div>; }
  }),
  childRoutes: [{
    path: "products",
    component: React.createClass({
      render() { return <div>{this.props.children}</div>; }
    }),
    childRoutes: [{
      path: "product/:id",
      component: React.createClass({
        // Render your component with contextual route props or anything else you need
        // If you need to test different combinations of properties, then setup a separate route configuration.
        render() { return <Breadcrumbs routes={this.props.routes} />; }
      }),
      childRoutes: []
    }]
  }]
}];

describe("Breadcrumbs component test suite:", () => {
  beforeEach(function() {
    // Render the entire route configuration with Breadcrumbs available on a specified route
    this.component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Router routes={routes} history={history} />);
    this.componentNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.component);
    this.breadcrumbNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.component).querySelector(".breadcrumbs");
  });

  it("should be defined", function() {
    expect(this.breadcrumbNode).toBeDefined();
  });

  /**
   * Now test whatever you need to
   */
```